# If I install Windows 10 in a virtualbox, will it be just as good as a dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, virtualbox, windows, wine

I love Ubuntu and would like to use it as a permanent host OS, however I do need Windows for some applications that wine cannot run (also I'm a bit of a gamer). If I installed Windows 10 64-bit in a virtualbox, would I still be able to run everything as if it were a dual-boot without any unsolvable issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes and No.**

**gaming perspective**:
Yes you can run, there are lot of constraints it depends on your system config.
(How much Ram memory, G memory and process capability.)

I would say minimum ram should be 8 gb if you want to play games like prince of Persia sands of time kind of games. And graphic memory also matters. Your graphic card should be well compatible to the Ubuntu(or any other distro).

If you want to run assassin's creed, witcher you need good graphics and lot of ram. still you may get lags.

My suggestion would be to have a dual boot. With my experience I hated running windows in virtual box and playing games.

**non-gaming perspective:**
 it is a charm running any application or software you want, it will run without any problem. make sure you have good ram capacity.
it is as if you run in dual boot.

good  for software
bad  for games ( AAA games).
works fine for games like pop, Mario, house of dead, etc.

**New Update on this Comment:**
Now you have Steam that can play AAA games so you can fully convert to ubuntu :)

Comment: Thanks for both perspectives. With the hardware I have, I don’t think that would be an issue. I was just curious to know if it’s possible to run everything smoothly even with the most ideal hardware. I’ll try it out though and see how it works out.

Comment: No problem, Glad i was a help

Answer (score 3):

### Performance in VirtualBox versus dual boot

- The ability to run particular tasks (with program packages and peripheral devices) is usually good in a virtual machine.
- The extra layer [of the virtual system] between the operating system and the hardware will make the system slower, and there will be less memory (RAM) available compared to running directly (booted into the hardware machine).
- Microsoft considers a virtual machine as a separate computer, which means that you need a separate licence for it. If your Windows system is installed by the vendor (OEM licence), I think it will not work in a virtual machine. (But you can install VirtualBox in Windows, and run Ubuntu in a virtual machine.)

So the answer depends on the hardware of the computer and what you want to do in the virtual system. Some tasks will work very well, other tasks will not run well at all and in some cases things will work, but not perform as well as in a dual boot system.

Finally, you should consider that a dual boot system must be rebooted to use the other operating system, while the host operating system will continue to run, when you start the virtual machine and run the other operating system.

Please try the different alternatives with the tasks you need and after that decide what is the best alternative in your particular case.

Comment: I have a pretty good setup. 32 gb ram, i7 8-core, nvidia 1060 (I think 3gb) but I can’t recall right now. I was thinking of throwing 16 gb ram on the VM and dedicated 4 cores or so. I’ll try that and see, but I’m dual booting right now and I’m not a huge fan, so guess the results will tell.

Comment: @Lumbeezl,  I think many application programs will work well in a virtual machine in that computer. There might be problems with some games. Good luck with the testing, and please share your results :-)